# Word 2007 Add-in

Tags: add-in, ribbon, word-2007

Okay this question is coming from someone who has never written any code beyond CSS, HTML and some php...

Pretty much I'm using Word all day and constantly needing to refer to just a couple of sites and resources on the web.

I would like to create a little add-in to go in the Ribbon in Word.

I have the full VB 2008 Proffesional edition.

Pretty much all I'd like it to do atm is have a new tab with a few easy to access buttons which link to specific URL's, although the ideal would be that pushing these links would also automatically log me into the websites at the same time.

Possible?

From this I'll hopefully be able to work off as I learn more...

Comment: I think your question has already been answered.  Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111050/developing-ms-word-add-in

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, check [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905533.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can definitly do this as a word add-in (the auto-login part may be tricky...). 
Here are some ressources:

- http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/6/1/a61dd5df-f52c-42d5-a95c-7a7fb7a6a466/ExtendedRibbon.wmv
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338198.aspx

However, there are easier ways to do this. I would rather create a toolbar in my Windows taskpane.